# Not able to read file data after counting number of lines

Tags: python, readfile

```
import sys
source = open(sys.argv[1], 'rt')
count_lines = len(source.readlines())
print count_lines
for row in source:
    print row
source.close()
```

I am trying to count the number of lines in a file and then reading the file line by line. count_lines returns the correct value but there is no output from `print row` . Is there something basic that I am doing wrong?

Comment: Seek back to the start of the file, you have consumed the file iterator after first iteration.

Comment: Or just close and reopen the file. Or use `linecache`.

Comment: As a side note, instead of `len(source.readlines())`, consider something like `sum(1 for line in source)` to avoid creating a giant list in memory that you don't need.

Comment: Or, alternatively, if you _do_ want the giant list (but, really, you don't…), you already read it into memory, so don't throw it away: `lines = source.readlines()`, then you can `close` the file and still `print len(lines)`, then `for row in lines:`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After calling `source.readlines()`, the file's current position is at the end of the file. You should call [source.seek](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html#methods-of-file-objects) with `0` as argument to set the current position at the beginning of the file.

If you're reading a large file, you also want to avoid the `readlines` call to avoid wasting (potentially a lot of) memory. You can do this by `sum(1 for _ in source)`.

Answer (score 0):

```
import sys
source = open(sys.argv[1], 'rt')
count_lines = len(source.readlines())
print count_lines
source.seek(0)
for row in source:
    print row
source.close()
```